# Inconsistent audio playback from audio tag in Safari on laptop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Using React, I'm using JavaScript (`play()`) to make two `audio` tags play 2 different .mp3 files (at completely separate times). The .mp3 files are short (less than a second).

```
import sound1 from 'sound1.mp3';
import sound2 from 'sound2.mp3';

<audio controls muted>
  <source src={sound1}></source>
</audio>

<audio controls muted>
  <source src={sound2}></source>
</audio>
```

```
audio {
  display: none;
}
```

1. In Safari 13.1.2, on my 13-inch MacBook Catalina, often, one of the sounds plays imperfectly - it's as if the start of the sound isn't heard. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0kWZ64qiuQ) of me demonstrating what the sound's really like against what it should be like. When the black piece moves, you'll need to turn your volume all the way up to hear a quiet, echoey noise. Then I play you how that file's supposed to sound.
2. When on my iPhoneX, in Chrome & Safari, the same sound (seemingly) fails to play at all. This may be explained by this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64275178/how-to-make-audio-playback-on-work-on-mobile) which says that sound won't play unless from a callback from an event handler that involves the user's physical participation e.g. `click`. This theory fits my case.

My question is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647163/how-to-make-a-sound-always-perfectly-with-the-audio-tag-in-html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952427/mobile-safari-skips-first-seconds-of-html-audio-on-play) which got no response. If you think it'd be useful for me to recreate this problem with a Sandbox I could try.

---

Personal note:

On my 13-inch MacBook Catalina:

- on Chrome both sounds work fine.
- in Safari, sound2 works imperfectly.

on my IPhoneX:

- on Chrome & Safari sound2 is sometimes audible later on.

---

EDIT:

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mshu0NmXqQo&feature=youtu.be) you can hear me playing back the problematic audio file in Finder. I play it the first time - fine; but the second+ time it makes the same incorrect sound heard in the browser!

Replacing the problematic audio file with a different audio-file brings success - and suggests the problem lies with the audio-file and not my implementation of it in the website. I'm willing to reframe this problem as a poorly performing audio-file but I really don't know. If this were the problem, my only recourse to avoid it would be replaying the audio-file in Finder and making sure it plays a consistent sound.

Comment: Workaround that worked for me found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952427/mobile-safari-skips-first-seconds-of-html-audio-on-play